# Prove that $S(m,n)$ is true for all $m \ge 1$ and $n \ge 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Prove that $S(m,n)$ is true for all $m \ge 1$ and $n \ge 1$. Suppose that

(i) $S(1,1)$ is true;

(ii) if $S(m,1)$ is true, then $S(m+1,1)$ is true;

(iii) if $S(m,n)$ is true for all $m$, then $S(m,n+1)$ is true for all $m$.

Prove that $S(m,n)$ is true for all $m \ge 1$ and $n \ge 1$.

proof.

Let $C$ be the set of all integers $p \ge m$ for which $P(m, 1)$ is false. If $C$ is empty, then we are done. Otherwise, there is a smallest integer $k$ in $C$. By (i), we have $k>1$, and so there is a statement $S(k-1,1)$. But $k-1$ implies that $k-1 \notin C$, for $k$ is the smallest integer in C. Thus, $S(k-1,1)$ is true, and this contradicts $k \in C$ by (ii). Thus, we have that $S(m,1)$ is true for all integers $m \ge 1$. 
Now, let $Q$ be the set of all integers $z > n$ for which $P(1,n)$ is false. If $Q$ is empty, we are done. Otherwise, there is a smallest integer $l$ in $C$. We have $l>1$, and so there exists a statement $S(1,l-1)$. Now, $l-1$ implies that $S(1,l-1)$ is true, and this contradicts $l \in Q$ by (iii). Therefore, we have that $S(m,n)$ is true for all $m \ge 1$ and $n \ge 1$. Q.E.D.

I kind of feel like I'm doing something wrong in this proof. Is it okay to introduce more than one contradiction in the same entire proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks valid. It is okay to use two contradictions in your proof, because you are actually proving two things via two separate proofs by contradiction.

You are first proving that $S(m,1)$ is true for all $m$ via a proof by contradiction.

Then you use this result to prove the desired result using another proof by contradiction.